# Div will not display when using an array

Tags: javascript

Trying to randomly generate one div from an array on each load of a page.

I've managed to put together bits from a few random image generators to create the below.

When the [0] in the array contains an image, like the rest, everything works as it should. Once I replace [0]'s image with a div or video, nothing at all displays and the page is blank.

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function random()
         {
             video = new Array(4);
             video[0] = "<div class="clip"> </div> ";
             video[1] = "<a href=''><img src='http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-3.jpg' alt='' /></a>";
             video[2] = "<a href=''><img src='http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-6.jpg' alt='' />";
             video[3] = "<a href=''><img src='http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-640-480-1.jpg' alt='' />";
             for(var i = 0; i < video.length; i++)
             {
                 index = Math.floor(Math.random() * video.length);
                 document.write(video[index]);
             }
         }
     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         random();
      </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: How come you're closing the first array member anchor tag but not the rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes.  Try:

`video[0] = "<div class=\"clip\"> </div>";`

or use singles:

`video[0] = "<div class='clip'> </div>";`

Also, you are aware your div is empty, right?  Unless your style does something to make it display something, it will appear blank.